# Unable to Clean Old Registry Errors

Tags: windows-registry

Good day Problem Solvers, I kindly ask for a solution to help me remove entries left by a previous OS from registry. I recently upgraded my OS from Win 8.1 to 10 but when I scan my registry with Ccleaner 5.0.8 I get an array of issues. See errors below:

```
ActiveX/COM Issue   RDSServer.DataFactory - {9381D8F5-0288-11d0-9501-00AA00B911A5}  HKCR\RDSServer.DataFactory  yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   RDSServer.DataFactory.6.0 - {9381D8F5-0288-11d0-9501-00AA00B911A5}  HKCR\RDSServer.DataFactory.6.0  yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   SAPIEngine.TTSEngine - {F51C7B23-6566-424C-94CF-2C4F83EE96FF}   HKCR\SAPIEngine.TTSEngine   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   SAPIEngine.TTSEngine.1 - {F51C7B23-6566-424C-94CF-2C4F83EE96FF} HKCR\SAPIEngine.TTSEngine.1 yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   SAPI_OneCoreEngine.TTSEngine - {F51C7B23-6566-424C-94CF-2C4F83EE96FF}   HKCR\SAPI_OneCoreEngine.TTSEngine   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   SAPI_OneCoreEngine.TTSEngine.1 - {F51C7B23-6566-424C-94CF-2C4F83EE96FF} HKCR\SAPI_OneCoreEngine.TTSEngine.1 yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000100-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000101-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000103-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000104-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000105-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000106-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000107-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000108-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\DAO\dao360.dll HKCR\CLSID\{00000109-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MapsBtSvcProxy.dll   HKCR\CLSID\{1965FEA3-3896-438B-B789-F5981797E7E7}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   LocalServer32\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AuthHost.exe  HKCR\CLSID\{31337EC7-5767-11CF-BEAB-00AA006C3606}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AuthHostProxy.dll    HKCR\CLSID\{5DE7918B-BFD7-4C1E-B4E0-B16D0A3EA76B}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ConnectedStorageService.ProxyStub.dll    HKCR\CLSID\{B2D2142A-9055-4C37-B3FA-EEFDD4C1DC59}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%CommonProgramFiles%\System\Ole DB\msdaora.dll   HKCR\CLSID\{e8cc4cbf-fdff-11d0-b865-00a0c9081c1d}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\SysWOW64\poliycmanager.dll    HKCR\CLSID\{E98B8DC5-72E3-48E4-A4BC-9393F3EA0DA5}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%SystemRoot%\System32\MSMiraDisp.dll HKCR\CLSID\{3a40a10e-ab54-4d64-a2a8-ec81ac256c22}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\System32\TetheringSettingHandler.dll  HKCR\CLSID\{A530D54A-DBA0-4b17-9F99-51A7A2CC17CA}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\System32\ConnectedStorageService.ProxyStub.dll    HKCR\CLSID\{B2D2142A-9055-4C37-B3FA-EEFDD4C1DC59}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\System32\QuickActionsPS.dll   HKCR\CLSID\{B35913A2-BE2E-4FA6-978C-3B130A7EFB98}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\C:\Windows\System32\poliycmanager.dll    HKCR\CLSID\{E98B8DC5-72E3-48E4-A4BC-9393F3EA0DA5}   yaddly
ActiveX/COM Issue   InProcServer32\%systemroot%\system32\wbem\netswitchteamcim.dll  HKCR\CLSID\{F43E8166-162C-4B12-8C2B-510D21516082}   yaddly
Missing TypeLib Reference   IHTMLCSSStyleDeclaration4 - {D6100F3B-27C8-4132-AFEA-F0E4B1E00060}  HKCR\Interface\{D6100F3B-27C8-4132-AFEA-F0E4B1E00060}   yaddly
Missing TypeLib Reference   ISyncEngineEvents - {0478ABF2-C52F-43DA-B7A3-F495A11BAF9F}  HKCR\Interface\{14B5B02C-08B8-44E5-AE0F-06DF616BBEFA}   yaddly
Missing TypeLib Reference   ISyncEngine - {0478ABF2-C52F-43DA-B7A3-F495A11BAF9F}    HKCR\Interface\{77435520-1089-42DF-B442-024DB87F36B4}   yaddly
Application Paths Issue licensemanagershellext.exe - C:\Windows\System32\licensemanagershellext.exe HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\licensemanagershellext.exe All users
Application Paths Issue SnippingTool.exe - %SystemRoot%\system32\SnippingTool.exe   HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\SnippingTool.exe   All users
```

Comment: Registry clearners are snake oil

Comment: thank you Ramhound for your kind feedback, would you recommend me to install windows 10 afresh

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: If you don't have actual problems with Windows, then just leave it alone.

Comment: @Ramhound: "snake oil": Not necessarily true. While removing unused registry entries often has no visible benefit, I've dealt with file association issues after updating a program where a file refuses to open in the correct program and CCleaner's registry cleaner feature fixed it. I've used CCleaner for many years (I learned about it in high school) without any issues whatsoever.

Comment: @DragonLord - The "snake oil" is the registry cleaners that remove every "error" they discover.  Modifying the registry to fix a file association is a specific task and not really even close to what I describe.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, was subject to the same issue.

### I performed the following to resolve the problem:

Within CCleaner, select 'Open in Regedit'.
Right click on the key entry and select 'Permissions' in the context menu.
From there, go to 'Advanced' and take ownership of the key [search for your user if need be] -> check both 'Replace owner on subcontainers and objects' and 'Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object'.
Under the permissions for each user, give each one full control (to make it quick and easy).

Now right click on the key and select delete -- you'll be able to delete the entry.

Comment: Good day, thank you for kind response and guidance. I'm trying to follow the instructions but I'm getting this error: Unable to save permission changes on RDServer.DataFactory. Access Denied. Kindly help, what am I doing wrong?