# How to get permissions to modify registry keys in System\DriverDatabase\DriverPackages

Tags: windows-8, permissions, windows-registry

It says I don't have permission to modify these keys.  I typed sudo but it just made fun of me.

Anyone know how I can get back at it?

Comment: What have you actually tried? It should be as simply as using an Administrator user to change the permissions.

Comment: Ok it works if I change the Owner/permissions on the direct parent folder, but I've got about 3 dozen of these registry keys to change, all in different folders.  Is there a better way than that?  Or a fast way to do that

Comment: You write a small program or a batch script.  What problem are you trying to solve by changing the permission of these keys anyways?

Comment: This one: http://superuser.com/questions/952315/error-1327-invalid-drive-windows-8/952335#952335
I don't know batch scripting, I was using a search and replace program which worked for 99% of the keys.

Comment: Can you edit your question in that case?  What you linked to was answer to a question.  That does not really explain what problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: My mistake, I copied to the URL box.  My problem is the question in that thread.  I recombined a partitioned drive and some registry keys still reference the old E:\ drive.  Since that doesn't exist I can't install or uninstall these programs.  I thought I had uninstalled everything but I missed LibreOffice.  And months later I find I actually want to use LibreOffice.

The search and replace program I found solved the LibreOffice issue but shed light that I had many other E:\ drive errors and now I want to resolve those.  But I need permission...

Comment: [You can use something like CCleaner to do a recursive permission change on a registry key](http://superuser.com/questions/947160/unable-to-clean-old-registry-errors?noredirect=1#comment1299780_947160)